# Create an alarm list

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to write a simple application on Android for my own use.

I want to add an alarm. How do I make a list of alarms and add them?

It's about something like the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the link of Android alarm app source code, [git_alarm_app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock)

it can be helpful if you are doing similar.. You can see how this app does things and help yourself..

Comment: the last commit on this app is before 4 years it gave me alot of errors in xml like 'error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent')' why

Comment: on what android version it is i tried many but looks the sdk is updated since then

Comment: Please have a look on code, how it deals with alarms, as i Said it can be helpful if you are doing  same kinda app!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout for items of the ListView.

You can find tutorials about this on Internet : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html 
http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

Comment: I know how to do ListView. But how add alarm to list ?